# Pros and cons of Nadaraya–Watson estimator vs. RKHS method?

Tags: nonparametric, kernel-trick, kernel-smoothing, nonparametric-regression

Recently I've been reading some materials about nonparametric methods. Two methods related to the word "kernel" rasied my interest-- **Nadaraya–Watson** estimator and **RKHS** method.

What's the difference? What are the pros and cons?